# order of output in printing dictionaries and sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set

Is there an algorithm in printing the contents of sets and dictionaries? What I mean is, let's say I have some set like this:

```
my_set = set({1,2.7,3,4.5,5})
```

If I print `my_set`, how do I know what order I'll get it in? I know it's using the same order over & over again for this particular set, but what if I don't know what my set is going to be? Is the order just random? Or is there an algorithm? How does this work for dictionaries, is it the same concept?

Comment: Sets use the same hashing algorithm, so the reasons for set ordering is the same as for dictionaries.

Comment: Sets and dicts are unordered. They may be the same with the same data, but not always (depending on insertion order)

Comment: It's implementation-specific, and not something you should depend on.  That's about all that can be said.